# Remove all the options from a multiple selectbox

Tags: javascript

If I try to remove all the options with the following code from a multiple select box, not all options will be removed.

What do I wrong?

```js
var e = document.getElementById("category2").options;

for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
  e[i].remove();
}
```

```html
<select id="category2" name="category_id[]" multiple="multiple" size="10">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can use a while loop to achieve this... `while (parent.firstChild) { parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild);}`

Comment: *What do I wrong?* - classic mistake. Play the loop on paper: `i=0 <? length=5`, yes, "1" gets deleted. The list is "2","3","4","5" now. `i=1 <? length=4`, yes, "3" gets deleted. The list is "2","4","5" now. `i=2 <? length=3`, yes, "5" gets deleted. The list is "2","4" now. `i=3 <? length=2`, no, the loop stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking for this ?

```js
bt_remove.onclick =_=>
  {
  [...category2.selectedOptions].forEach(opt => opt.remove() );
  
  /*
   for just unselect:
  [...category2.selectedOptions].forEach(opt => opt.selected = false );
  */
  }
```

```html
<select id="category2" multiple="multiple" size="5">
  <option value="1"          >--- 1 ---</option>
  <option value="2" selected >--- 2 ---</option>
  <option value="3"          >--- 3 ---</option>
  <option value="4" selected >--- 4 ---</option>
  <option value="5" selected >--- 5 ---</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<button id="bt_remove"> remove selects</button>
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, thank you. But this type of code is completely new to me.

Comment: @Arthur some docs : [selectedOptions property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions) , 

[Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) , 

[Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) , 

[Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that every time you run `.remove()`, `e.length` gets decremented by one, but `i` stays just as high, so eventually it will be less than `i`.

To fix this, just create a copy of `e.length` (so it doesn't change) and remove `e[0]` each time. If you keep removing `e[i]`, then `i` will be larger than `e.length` and the element won't exist:

```js
let e = document.getElementById("category2").options;

const temp = e.length;
for (let i = 0; i < temp; i++) {
  e[0].remove();
}
```

```html
<select id="category2" name="category_id[]" multiple="multiple" size="10">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your question you have 1 selectbox and your answer is this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#category2 option').forEach(opt=>{
    opt.remove();
});
```

if you have multiple selectbox, you can use this

```
document.querySelectorAll('#category1 option, #category2 option').forEach(opt=>{
    opt.remove();
});
```

or use function

```
function removeOpt( selector ){
    document.querySelectorAll(selector+' option').forEach(opt=>{
        opt.remove();
    });
}
removeOpt( '#category2' );
removeOpt( '#otherSelectTag' );
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a little faster and simpler:

```js
document.getElementById("category2").options.length = 0;
```

```html
<select id="category2" name="category_id[]" multiple="multiple" size="10">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why was my solution voted down? It resolves the issue, does it not?

Comment: I guess it's because you didn't read the text of the question carefully: `not all options will be removed.`

Comment: Remove all the options from a multiple selectbox

Comment: It is pretty obvious now that you're right since the asker selected your response as the accepted one, but I understood that the asker wanted to remove ALL the options as the title says "Remove ALL the options from a multiple selectbox" and then in the explanation it says "If I try to remove ALL the options with the following code from a multiple select box, not all options will be removed. What do I wrong?" So I understood that asker was not able to write code that could remove all the options.